# binary float infinity -oracle command in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have following oracle query that need to be converted in to snowflake. Does anyone know an exception for binary_float_infinity in snowflake?

```
nvl(bl, -binary_float_infinity)
```

in oracle documentation the meaning for binary_float_infinity is **Single-precision positive infinity**
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowflake floats will report `inf` for positive infinity.

`select pow(100::float, 10000000000::float);`

You can check for the condition too:

`select pow(100::float, 10000000000::float) = 'inf';`

Some mathematical operations that other languages report as `inf` generate an error in Snowflake, such as dividing by zero.

That can be checked using JavaScript, which does report division by zero as positive or negative infinity.

```
create or replace function DIV2(A float, B float)
returns float
language javascript
as
$$
    return A/B;
$$;

select DIV2(1,0);
select DIV2(-1, 0);
```